# How to transform a Pandas dataframe so same rows become columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following DataFrame:

| id | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Elle | 567998 |
| 1 | Rand | 1234 |
| 1 | Danny | 5678 |
| 2 | Rand | 91011 |
| 2 | Danny | 121314 |
| 2 | Elle | 151413 |

How do I transform it into a following dataframe:

| A | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Elle | 567998 | 151413 |
| Rand | 1234 | 91011 |
| Danny | 5678 | 121314 |

I've tried using loops and Series but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. The only issue is that the new columns, which should be named after the id column, in this case 1 and 2, are named 0 and 1. How would I change that?